# Mysql Join performance MongoDB, Cassandra

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, performance, cassandra

I have a join query which takes a lot of time to process.

```
SELECT
COUNT(c.id)
FROM `customers` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN `setting` AS `ssh` ON `c`.`shop_id` = `ssh`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `customer_extra` AS `cx` ON `c`.`id` = `cx`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `customers_address` AS `ca` ON `ca`.`id` =            `cx`.`customer_default_address_id`
LEFT JOIN `lytcustomer_tier` AS `ct` ON `cx`.`lyt_customer_tier_id` = `ct`.`id`
WHERE (c.shop_id = '12121') AND ((DATE(cx.last_email_open_date) > '2019-11-08'));
```

This is primarily because the table 'customers' has 2 million records.

I could go over into indexing etc. But, the larger point is, this 2.5 million could become a billion records 1 day.

I'm looking for solutions which can enhance performance. 
I've given thought to

a) horizontal scalability. -: distribute the mysql table into different sections and query the count independently.

b) using composite indexes.

c) My favourite one  -: Just create a seperate collection in  mongodb or redis which only houses the count(output of this query) Since, the count is just 1 number. this will not require a huge size aka better query performance (Only question is, how many such queries are  there, because that will increase size of the new collection)

Comment: First of all, since you do `AND ((DATE(cx.last_email_open_date) > '2019-11-08'));`, that already made `customers` table to `INNER JOIN` with `customer_extra` table. So maybe you want to change it a bit to `FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN customer_extra AS cx ON ... ` then only `LEFT JOIN` other tables?

Comment: Thx. Make  this an answer. I will accept it

Comment: Ok, but does it improve performance? If so, how much has improved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it improve performance:

```
SELECT
COUNT(c.id)
FROM `customers` AS `c`
INNER JOIN `customer_extra` AS `cx` ON `c`.`id` = `cx`.`customer_id`
LEFT JOIN `setting` AS `ssh` ON `c`.`shop_id` = `ssh`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `customers_address` AS `ca` ON `ca`.`id` =            `cx`.`customer_default_address_id`
LEFT JOIN `lytcustomer_tier` AS `ct` ON `cx`.`lyt_customer_tier_id` = `ct`.`id`
WHERE (c.shop_id = '12121') AND ((DATE(cx.last_email_open_date) > '2019-11-08'));
```

As I mention in the comment, since the condition `AND ((DATE(cx.last_email_open_date) > '2019-11-08'));`, already made `customers` table to `INNER JOIN` with `customer_extra` table, you might just change it to `INNER JOIN customer_extra AS cx ON c.id = cx.customer_id` and follow it with other `LEFT JOIN`.

The `INNER JOIN` will at least get the initial result to only return any customer who have last_email_open_date value based on what has been specified.

Answer (score 1):

- Say `COUNT(*)`, not `COUNT(c.id)`
- Remove these; they slow down the query without adding anything that I can see:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN  `setting` AS `ssh`  ON `c`.`shop_id` = `ssh`.`id`
  LEFT JOIN  `customers_address` AS `ca`  ON `ca`.`id` = `cx`.`customer_default_address_id`
  LEFT JOIN  `lytcustomer_tier` AS `ct`  ON `cx`.`lyt_customer_tier_id` = `ct`.`id`
  ```
- `DATE(...)` makes that test not "sargable".  This works for `DATE` or `DATETIME`; and this is much faster:

  ```
  cx.last_email_open_date > '2019-11-08'
  ```
- Consider whether that should be `>=` instead of `>`.
- Need an index on `shop_id`.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)
- Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `JOIN` would work equally well.
- If `customer_extra` is columns that should have been in `customer`, now is the time to move them in.  That would let you use this composite index for even more performance:

  ```
  INDEX(shop_id, last_email_open_date)   -- in this order
  ```

With those changes, a billion rows in MySQL will probably not be a problem.  If it is, there are still more fixes I can suggest.